# PHP Warning: [mysql error 3] Error writing file '/tmp/

Tags: mysql, centos, centos6, tmp

Good eveing all,

I have a VPS running CentOS 6 and it is running remi-test install of PHP (5.4.8) and MySQL (5.5.28) 1cpu, 2G RAM, 200G storage. Its for hosting my gallery of photographs using Piwigo. The database has 1,385,133 records and takes up 60.8 MiB according to PHPmyAdmin. I have full root access and I have been doing some stuff in SSH but its still all new to me.

I keep seeing this error, it seems to cause the CPU usage of the server to go high. Seems to only be caused by the web spiders but its only happening a few times a day.

```
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: [mysql error 3] Error writing file '/tmp/MYq8M8yg' (Errcode: 28)
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: SELECT id
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: FROM piwigo_images i
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: INNER JOIN piwigo_image_category ic ON id=ic.image_id
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: INNER JOIN piwigo_image_tag it ON id=it.image_id
[warn] [client] mod_fcgid: stderr: WHERE tag_id IN (6,18,54,55,445,714)
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: GROUP BY id
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id)=6
[warn] [client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: ORDER BY file ASC, date_creation DESC in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/gallery/include/dblayer/functions_mysql.inc.php on line 770
[client IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/gallery/include/dblayer/functions_mysql.inc.php on line 200
```

A quick df -h shows,

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            4.0G  692M  3.3G  17% /
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  4.0G  1.5G  2.4G  39% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var  148G   43G   98G  31% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home 4.0G  136M  3.7G   4% /home
none                 1000M  112K 1000M   1% /tmp
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Guys, you reaeeeaaaalllllly need to read the questions (***and answers***) before just blindly migrating them over to Server Fault. This is getting beyond ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 28 means "no space left on device".

Sometimes MySQL processes complex queries in multiple steps while storing results of intermediate steps in the /tmp directory. Even if a single query does not use all the space you have, running multiple queries at the same time on a busy server might.

I think you have two options:

1. Optimize your queries to process less data at a time. In the posted query the problem most likely are the inner joins, which create a temporary result set containing all possible combinations of images, categories and tags, which is much more than the mentioned 1.3M records.
2. Throw resources at the problem: Give more space to /tmp or move the MySQL temporary directory [somewhere else](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html).

Comment: In theory the tmp is made up of the spare space left by what I have yet to allocate to a drive. So it has 1000M. But I have now set it to use /var/tmp as that has 98G spare. The only issue is how do I make sure that mysql has the correct permissions to use the folder?

Comment: You could create a /var/tmp/mysql and let user MySQL runs with own it.